# XSD type that is a list and has attributes

Tags: list, xsd, attributes

Here is an example of what I'd like to be able to do as a sample of XML (take note of the `file` elements):

```
...
<run-list>
  <topic name="topic1"/>
  <topic name="topic2">
    <file number="2"/>
    <file number="3">
      /a/b/c /a/b/d /a/b/g/h/i
    </file>
  </topic>
</run-list>
...
```

The `run-list` element can contain any number of `topic` elements. The `topic` element may contain zero or more `file` elements. The `file` element has the `number` attribute (required) and may contain zero or more path strings (*the list*).

I can't figure out how to define a schema type to allow for the definition of the `file` element as described above. I need the `file` element to have the `number` attribute and I'd like to be able to specify an optional list of path values. I have been able to define simple list types for other situations, but they don't have any attributes.

I have been able to do something that is close to this, but needed to define another schema type for the paths and implement it as an element within the `file` element. So I'd have something like this:

```
...
<file number="3">
   <path>/a/b/c</path>
   <path>/a/b/d</path>
   <path>/a/b/g/h/i</path>
</file>
...
```

I'd like to avoid having to define a separate schema type and element to specify the path(s) under a given `file` element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Here's the schema that seems to work:

```
<xs:complexType name="TestSpecification">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="topic" type="TopicSpecification"
      minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TopicSpecification">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="file" type="FileSpecification" minOccurs="0"
      maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="FileSpecification">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="EntityPathList">
      <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="EntityPathList">
  <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
</xs:simpleType>
```

If anyone sees any potential problems with this, suggestions on how to improve or alternatives, please feel free to comment.